# PHP: How to fetch a single value from sqlite table

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to access sqlite from PHP script. Not sure how to fetch a single value from table.

```
<?php

if ($dbhandle = sqlite_open('c:/sqlite/test.db', 0666, $sqliteerror)) 
{

$sql = "SELECT max (user_id) from persons";
    $res = sqlite_query($dbhandle, $sql);

    if (sqlite_num_rows($result)>0) {
        echo sqlite_fetch_single($result) ;
}  
}       

?>
```

I am getting following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\fetch_db.php on line 3

Just to add i am using Sqlite3.And even if I use PDo function I am getting error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\fetch_db.php on line 4

```
<?php

$db =  new PDO("sqlite:c:/sqlite/test.db");
$q1 = echo $db->query('select mx(person_id) from persons');
while($r = $q1->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
   echo  $r['id'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you have SQLIte installed on your server? http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php

Comment: `Since PHP 5.0 this extension was bundled with PHP. Beginning with PHP 5.4, this extension is available only via PECL.` http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error that there is no `sqlite_open` function because you don't have installed SQLite on your PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php

From URL:

> Since PHP 5.0 this extension was bundled with PHP. Beginning with PHP 5.4, this extension is available only via PECL.
>
> Windows users must enable php_sqlite.dll inside of php.ini in order to use these functions. A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the building on Windows section.
>
> Windows builds must also enable PDO because as of PHP 5.1.0 it depends on it. So, php.ini will end up with something like this:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

Comment: I have updated my pp.ini file with `extension=php_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll` but still getting the same error